# ListView MouseClick event not triggered when clicking on empty areas

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, events, contextmenu

I have a `ListView` control that shows files inside a folder in a grid layout. And I have a context menu with three `Items` that should behave like this:

1. If user right clicks on a file in the `ListView` the context menu will show all its 3 `Items`
2. If user right clicks on an empty space in the `ListView` the first `Item` of the context view should be invisible.

This is where I add my events and the code for the `MouseClick` event of my `ListView`:

```
this.listviewFiles.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listViewFiles_MouseClick);

private void listViewFiles_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (listviewFiles.FocusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
        {
            contextMenuFilesListbox.Items[0].Visible = false;
            contextMenuFilesListbox.Items[1].Visible = false;                                      
        }
        else
        {
            contextMenuFilesListbox.Items[0].Visible = true;
            contextMenuFilesListbox.Items[1].Visible = true;                    
        }
        contextMenuFilesListbox.Show(Cursor.Position);                
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I right-click on an empty area in my `listViewFiles_MouseClick` event is not triggered at all. So I cannot bring back the invisible `Item` in the context menu.

Comment: Try Using a Transparent background for the listview

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad is it possible to have a `ListView` with a BackColor property of `Color.Transparent`?

Comment: I thought you are working on WPF!

Answer (score 10):

The `MouseClick` won't work unless you hit an `Item` label. The `MouseDown` is nice and does also trigger when hitting a `SubItem` label or the empty space (`None`).

Checking what you are hitting is best done using a `ListViewHitTestInfo` object.

Here is how it should work:

```
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo HI = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (HI.Location == ListViewHitTestLocations.None)  
        {
            contextMenuFilesListbox.Items[0].Visible = false;
            contextMenuFilesListbox.Items[1].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            contextMenuFilesListbox.Items[0].Visible = true;
            contextMenuFilesListbox.Items[1].Visible = true;
        }
        contextMenuFilesListbox.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way to do this only on mouse double click? I've trying to get a listview to do something only on double clicking an empty space on the listview.

Comment: Yes, I think you can by testing e.Clicks to be equal 2. Example: Add a MouseDoubleClick event and in the Mousedown write: `if (e.Clicks == 2) listView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender, e)`;

Comment: I got all excited for a sec after reading your comment, lol, but when I tested it, it just keeps telling me 1 click, no matter how many times I click. i.e. I have a `listViewProxies_MouseUp` event, and added this to test: `Debug.WriteLine("Clicks: " + e.Clicks.ToString());` and then hammer an empty space in the listview, like way toward the bottom, but it just says 1 click. =/

Comment: It still the MouseDown event you need to use!

Comment: When it comes to a double-click, what's the difference between MouseDown and MouseUp?

Comment: Well as it stands the MouseDown eent is the only one that will be detected in the emtpy area of an LV. So that is what you need to code for. In it can can still test to see if it is part of a double click and can then call a Doubleclick event, just as I showed above. Why the MouseUp won't work is maybe explained in the sources, but then maybe it isn't..